# How to avoid saving dictionary data to a text file which results in creating multiple dictionary in saved text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to save some user input in dictionary format to a text file. The issue is that instead of saving the data as continuous key value pair format, multiple dictionaries are getting created. How can I avoid this?

```
from pathlib import Path

username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")
my_dict = {username: password}
myfile = Path('sample.txt')
myfile.touch(exist_ok=True)

with open('sample.txt', 'a') as data:
   data.write(str(my_dict))
```

Current sample text output:

```
{'1': '1'}{'2': '2'}
```

Expected output:

```
{'1': '1','2': '2'}
```

Comment: Don't use a text file for this using the string representation of the python object, that isn't what those are designed for. Use some serialization format, like JSON or pickle. Deserialize your existing data, augment the data structure, and then serialize it again. Or use a database, like sqlite, which comes with python

Comment: You are appending a new dictionary each time, but you are not telling your program to take into account anything that might already exist. So the expected output is actually your 'current sample text output'.

You could implement a way to read the contents that are already there as a dictionary, then add your newest value to that dictionary, and rewrite the file. This will write the dictionary how you would want it.

You could adjust the write to delete the last '}', add a comma, and write the string `" 'key': 'value'}"` explicitly.

But as juanpa.arrivillaga said, this is not the way.

Comment: To read: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html | How to do it with json: Load json file. Add stuff like you would normally to a dictionary. Write (don't append) json to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

There are three things you should change in your program. Firstly if use the `update` method it will add the value correctly to the `dict`, secondly use a serialization format like json instead of a text file, lastly when writing to the file simply overwrite it in `w` mode with the `dict`

**Here is the code:**

```
from pathlib import Path
import json

myfile = Path('sample.json')
myfile.touch(exist_ok=True)
#reading the file intoa dictionary
with open(myfile,'r') as file:
    my_dict = json.load(file)

#getting inputs
username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")
#adding the data as a continues key value format to the dict
my_dict.update({username : password})

#write the data to the json file in overwrite mode
with open(myfile,'w') as file:
   json.dump(my_dict, file)
```

**File Ouput:**

```
{"1": "1", "2": "2"}
```

For more information with working with `json` in python see [this](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.htm)

*note the json file should have a {} the first time the program is run to prevent errors*

Comment: just what I wanted terminator , Hasta la vista, baby

Comment: @Lakpa Its a pleasure